# scala exactly matching a word in a given string

Tags: regex, scala, replace

I am trying to replace an exact match of a word in a string using scala

```
"\\bhello\\b".r.replaceAllIn("hello I am helloclass with hello.method","xxx")

output >> xxx I am helloclass with xxx.method
```

what I want is to replace if the word is exactly hello not hello in helloclass and hello.method

```
xxx I am helloclass with hello.method
```

and if the input strings are

```
"hello.method in helloclass says hello"
"hello.method says hello from helloclass"
"hello.method in helloclass says Hello and hello"
```

output should be

```
"hello.method in helloclass says xxx"
"hello.method says xxx from helloclass"
"hello.method in helloclass says Hello and xxx"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how you want to define "word". If the "words" are what you get when you split a string by sequences of whitespace characters, then you can write:

```
"(?<=^|\\s)hello(?=\\s|$)".r.replaceAllIn("hello I am helloclass with hello.method","xxx")
```

where `(?<=^|\\s)` means "preceded by start-of-string or whitespace" and `(?=\\s|$)` means "followed by whitespace or end-of-string".

Note that this would view (for example) the string  `Tell my wife hello.` as containing four "words", of which the fourth is `hello.`, *not* `hello`. You can address that by defining "word" in a more complicated way, but you need to define it first.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Yes, my words are separated by spaces. Do you know how to form this regex with a variable? I tried ("(?<=^|\\s)"+str+"(?=\\s|$)").r but it didn't work

Comment: @yalkris how exactly it didn't work? if you defined str, this should work

Comment: @yalkris: What was `str` set to?

Comment: Sorry, it worked. Previously I was trying `var str: String="hello" ("(?<=^|\\s)"+str+"(?=\\s|$)").r.replaceAllIn("hello.method in helloClass says hello","xxx"))` and I didn't see the output. But when I used `println(("(?...xxx"))` I saw the output. I don't understand why I should use println()