# matching words/phrases in scala on as is basis

Tags: string, scala, pattern-matching, match

I have to find if a given phrase/word exists in a paragraph or not. Here's what I have done, given "wordlist" is the paragraph in which I have to look for phrases/words and "words" is the phrase/word.

```
if (wordlist contains words){println(words)}
```

But this also does substring search as:
`"value of this" contains "val"` is `true`. I want "true" in only those cases where the phrase/word is present as is and is not a part of other string in "wordlist". So,`"value of this"`contains `"x"` should give `true` for the following values of x:
`"value", "value of", "this"` etc and give `false` for `"val", "alue", "e of" "his"` etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala exactly matching a word in a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652447/scala-exactly-matching-a-word-in-a-given-string)

Comment: Use `\b` + `word` + `\b`, or `(?<!\S)` + `word` + `(?!\S)`.

Comment: could you explain this please?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652447/scala-exactly-matching-a-word-in-a-given-string

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit like trying to find a sublist in a list, so one approach would be to convert both into lists of words, as follows:

```
wordlist.split(" ") containsSlice words.split(" ")
```

From the REPL, it looks like this meets your requirements (if not please expand!):

```
scala> def hasPhrase(wordList:String,words:String) = wordList.split(" ") containsSlice words.split(" ")
hasPhrase: (wordList: String, words: String)Boolean

scala> hasPhrase("value of this","value")
res13: Boolean = true

scala> hasPhrase("value of this","value of")
res14: Boolean = true

scala> hasPhrase("value of this","val")
res15: Boolean = false

scala> hasPhrase("value of this","his")
res16: Boolean = false
```

Splitting both strings is not going to be efficient across big strings or a large number of strings. If your use case allows, you could split the long phrase just once (so that you can do `wordlistAsCollection containsSlice words.split(" ")`). You could also try a regex approach as suggested in the comments, perhaps along the lines of:

```
def hasPhrase(wordList:String,words:String) = 
  new scala.util.matching.Regex("\\b"+words+"\\b")
    .findFirstMatchIn(wordList)
    .isDefined
```

Comment: no, I do not want to do this as there are phrases which I want to match and they have to be matched as phrases rather than as words.

Comment: this solves my problem but has slowed down my code. I have to do this matching on 25 million records

Answer (score 0):

I believe to make it faster you need to build an index (although initial cost will be high since you need to build the index, but then matching process will be much faster). Otherwise you will have to traverse all the possibilities, which will be slow.

I'll use `"value of this"` as an example. An idea would be, building a `Map` (sorted) based number of chars for all combination of phrases.

`value` would be `Map(Map(a -> 1, e -> 1, l -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 1) -> List(value))`.

`value of` would be `Map(Map(  -> 1, a -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 1, l -> 1, o -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 1) -> List(value of))`

and so on.

Then, when trying to check whether a phrase/word exist, you can just match according to the frequency of characters. You'll then get a `List` which you have to check again.